# how to provide value to parent class constructor where parent constructor have more argument than child class from static void main in c#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

i have a parent class Customer which has 3 `properties` **

> **CID,Bal,Cname**

** 
and i have a child class which has 1 property Stats.now i want to supply the value to parent class `constructor` from my child class constructor by static void main.
i want to provide value to parent class constructor from base class only.
my code below

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stat s1 = new Stat(false);//want to provide value to base class constructor from here only.
        }
    }

    class Customer
    {
        int _Cid, _Bal;

        string _Cname;

        public int CID
        {
            get
            {
                return _Cid;
            }
            set
            {
                _Cid= value;
            }
        }

        public int Bal
        {
            get
            {
                return _Bal;
            }
            set
            {
                _Bal = value;
            }
        }
        public string Cname
        {
            get
            {
                return _Cname;
            }
            set
            {
                _Cname = value;
            }
        }

        public Customer(int _Cid,int _Bal,String _Cname)
        {
            this._Cid=_Cid;
            this._Cname = _Cname;
            this._Bal = _Bal;
        }
    }


    class Stat:Customer
    {
        bool _Status;

        public bool Stats
            {
            get
            {
                return _Status;
            }
            set
            {
                _Status= value;
            }
    }
        public void display()
        {
        }
        public Stat(bool _Status):base(int _Cid, int _Bal, String _Cname) //child class constructor how can i supply value to parent class constructor.
        {
            this._Status = _Status;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to define a derived class constructor that accepts the proper values, and then pass them.

Comment: already have @MarkBenningfield

Comment: No, you haven't. The code as posted won't even compile.

Comment: yeah because i don' know how to supply value to parent class constructor @MarkBenningfield

Comment: See [Instance Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/instance-constructors#example-3)

Comment: The arguments that you pass in `: base(...)` should come from the constructor of the derived class. (e.g. `public Derived(bool a, int b) : base(b)`)

Comment: so u mean that u mean parent class will always have less param than child class ? @John

Comment: can you please help i am new to c# @John

Comment: @Deepak did my answer solve your issue, or can I offer any more assistance?

Answer (score 2):

Your base class constructor is this:

```
public Customer(int _Cid,int _Bal,String _Cname)
```

Your derived class constructor is this:

```
public Stat(bool _Status)
```

In C# when you instantiate a derived class, the base class must be called. Where the base class only has a parameterless constructor, this is done implicitly before the derived class constructor body is executed. If the base class does not have a parameterless constructor, you must explicitly call it using `base`.

Take this example:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Person,
    Animal,
    Derived
}

public class Base
{
    public Base(MyEnum classType)
    {
    }
}

public class Person : Base
{

}
```

There's two ways you can do this: accept the argument to `Person` and pass it to the base constructor:

```
public class Person : Base
{
    public Person(MyEnum classType) : base(classType)
    {
        // this will be executed after the base constructor completes
    }
}
```

or by hard-coding the value (imagine that MyEnum contains a value `Person`):

```
public class Person : Base
{
    public Person() : base(MyEnum.Person)
    {
        // this will be executed after the base constructor completes
    }
}
```

Note that you can have multiple constructors, so if the values should be instantiated with some defaults by derived classes, you could define a different `protected` constructor to be used by derived classes. `protected` ensures that it can only be called by derived classes, and not by anyone calling `new Base(...)`:

```
public class Base
{
    private readonly MyEnum _classType;

    public Base(MyEnum classType)
    {
        _classType = classType;
    }

    protected Base()
    {
        _classType = classType.Derived;
    }
}

public class Person : Base
{
    public Person() : base()
    {
        // this will be executed after the base constructor completes
    }        
}
```

There's no relationship between the number of arguments in the base and derived classes. There exists only a simple requirement: a derived constructor *must* call (and satisfy any argument requirements) its base class constructor where the base class constructor takes arguments, or there is more than one.

In your specific example, you probably intended this:

```
public Stat(bool _Status, int _Cid, int _Bal, String _Cname) : base(_Cid, _Bal, _Cname)
```

As a side note, naming arguments `_Cid` is a bit strange. The prefix `_` typically indicates that it is a private field in a class. Normal C# conventions use camel case (`camelCaseArgumentName`) for method arguments.

Comment: A small correction: When the base class has *only* a parameter-less constructor it is called implicitly. If it has another constructor as well you have to explicitly call one of them in the child class constructor.

Comment: @Zohar Good point. :)